# Text Positioning in Span

Tags: html, css, html-table, styles

I'm trying to show image and text similar to the attached image:

[image]

Here is my code which I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/ghdqty2w/1/

I have included 3 spans in one div, but I'm not able to set the position of span with respect to the image.

```
<div>
                    <span>
                        <img id="productURL" src="https://images.app.goo.gl/xH1qtjAt7krCiXicA" alt="Product Image" width="50" height="60"/>
                    </span>
                    <span style="bottom:10px;">
                        Product Name X 5
                        <br/>
                        50 Kg | 6 Cs
                    </span>
                    <span>
                        500
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please consider creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your current issue with [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
        <span>
          <img
            id="productURL"
            src="https://usabilla.com/graphics/resources/usabilla-logo.png"
            alt="Product Image"
            width="50"
            height="60"
          />
        </span>
        <div>
          <span style="bottom:10px;">
            Product Name X 5
            <br />
            50 Kg | 6 Cs
          </span>
          <span>500</span>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a position? Like for example "position: absolute" before the "bottom"?
Things like bottom, top, left or right don't work unless you tell them which kind of positioning you're giving it.